# how can i make drone fly in same location? (not go left, right, forward, back)

Tags: drone

I made quad drone that use PID control to fly and drone fly well.
I set the PID values, and the drone always have difference force, so drone always go left or right or forward or back. It can't fly in the same location.

I would like to make the drone fly in the same location. However, I don't know how to make it. Maybe this is hovering. But i don't know any hint about it.
please let me know how to fly drone in same location!

Comment: Think about it for a moment -- how do you know that the drone is not holding a fixed position? Now, how would the drone itself know? Obviously, it needs a sensor or a signal that tells it what its position actually is. One common way to do this is to add a GPS receiver to the drone and write some software that uses the GPS data in a feedback loop to maintain a given position or follow a given trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run positional control with a PID unless you have a control signal for position. You might be running PID off of one of your sensors (which is probably an accelerometer) and your disturbance forces (shown below as Td are the other forces acting on the drone and include wind and sensor, and control error) are too great relative to your desired signal. To truly run you position control closed loop, it's best to actually sense position instead of an estimated position (from an inertial sensor).

[image]

See [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10052/position-control-vs-velocity-control-vs-torque-control) example for floor robots, of why it's difficult even if you almost know where your robot is.

There are several ways to do this:

1. Add GPS, or even better [GPS with RTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) to follow to allow the drone to locate its position.
2. If you know something about the area the drone is flying in, you can use [Monte Carlo localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_localization) to let the drone estimate its postion relative to a preprogrammed map internal to the drone.
3. There are also infrared tracking systems that can give mm accuracy but they are beyond most budgets.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to "trim" the drone: add slight modifications to the control positions to minimise drift.

But getting a drone to stay in place in the presence of wind conditions is actually really difficult. GPS is not nearly precise enough for this. IMUs help but are also subject to drift. The most reliable way for small indoor drones is optical stabilisation. This is easy if you can have fixed beacons (you can potentially do it with a Wiimote on the drone and the "sensor bar" on the floor), but otherwise you have to have a camera and fairly computationally-intensive vision system. It functions rather like an optical mouse, using features on the ground to determine the movement of the drone.

Comment: "GPS is not nearly precise enough for this. IMUs help but are also subject to drift." I'd like to add that this is precisely why you use *both* at the same time. The IMU provides precise, high update rate and low latency translation and rotation information, while the accurate but slow GPS corrects the IMU in the long term and thus prevents drift.